# ¿Por qué angularJS escribe el literal {{"add-Successfully" | translate}} en lugar del texto en sí?

Tags: angularjs

Estoy tratando de que cuando se agreguen datos correctamente al servidor, me confirme dicha operación a través de un mensaje diciendo, **agregado exitosamente**, o que me lo muestre en inglés, lo cual dependería del idioma que use el usuario.

El problema, es que no despliega el mensaje correctamente y me imprime literalmente `{{"add-Successfully" | translate}}` en lugar de imprimir **agregado exitosamente**.

```
alertify.success('{{"add-Successfully" | translate}}');
```

Comment: Por favor agrega todas las partes relevantes de tu código. Intenta crear un [mcve]

Comment: basicamente solo quiero imprimir informacion dentro de un alert algo asi alert({{add | traslate }});

Comment: debajo de tu pregunta, está el enlace para [edit]. Por favor agrega el código a la pregunta (donde se puede leer bien el código con formato)

Answer (score 0):

Deberías utilizar el filtro translate de distinta manera:

```
 alertify.success($filter('translate')('add-Successfully'));
```

Asegúrate de Inyectar la dependencia $filter al modulo correspondiente.

Comment: gracias por el aporte are los sugerido